# apache htaccess - trailing slash and single entry point

Tags: apache, .htaccess, entry-point, trailing-slash

I need to have one entry point for my application - index.php. 
Before, i used to have such line of code:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]`

Now, i need to force trailing slashes. I found out, that I can use such line:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]`

But I want to know, how can I make it work both together.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Why not? Thats exactly how I use it in my application: Every request ends in calling index.php and everything after the / can be read out there to do the routing...

Comment: Because you'll have URL like: example.com/index.php/page
It's bad UI to have index.php in your URL.

Comment: ...then remove the `R=xxx`, because thats whats triggering the "external redirect"!